# How can i put a editor on a jfacedialog in RCP?

Tags: java, swt, rcp, jface

I want to put a editor on a jface dialog.is it possible to put a editor on jface dilaog.I know hopw to put it on workbench but i donot have any clue how to put it on jface dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and No. The `IEditorPart` is specific for the RCP platform, so it would be silly to hack it into a dialog.

BUT. I'm guessing you want some widgets on a canvas, to edit an entity. You don't need an editor for that, you simply put all the stuff you need in a `Composite` inside your dialog.